# Performance in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I'm building an simple voting, unique viewer, unique download count Etc. function in php/mysql and I have one question regarding performance:

Due of many action on this small system I want to know what is the best practice on this, using multiple `INT` columns or 1 single `VARCHAR` column, of course  in performance terms:

```
$uniqueid= STRING generated from system (ip, cookies Etc)
$contentid = INT ID on primary key of content table
$contenttype = INT 0-n   ( comment = 0, poll = 1, filedownload = 2 Etc).
$action = INT 0-n ( vote = 0,  view = 1, download = 2 Etc)


SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `uid` = '$uniqueid' AND `cid` = '$contentid' AND `ct` = '$contenttype' AND `action` = '$action' ;
```

Or this:

```
$key  = "$uniqueid-$contentid-$contenttype-$action";

SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `key` = '$key';
```

Comment: This seems like an example of premature optimization.  There is no reason not to use four columns for four different attributes with a variety of types.  You should go with that solution, unless you have very specific and arcane performance requirements.

Comment: as Gordon said, there's no need to complicate things. MySQL should be able to lookup 1M+ rows/second easily. Best optimization is no optimization, don't worry about it until you realize you need to optimize. regardless, storing data like in the second case will be a nightmare later on.

Comment: Hi,thanks for quick reply. Yes, it is an typical premature optimization and I'm aware of it :) And was my fault also on choosing terms, performance is an ambitious word for this incomplete example. In developing, performance includes a wide list of processes and components acting in the most efficient way. The right term was speed, just the difference of speed on query indexed VARCHAR vs INT. Anyway due some changes on my "small" project, the more reasonable solution is to use multiple INT columns. Is more re-usable on future features and I don't have this "problem" on mysql cluster anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep them seperate.

- You may want to remove one of the features later
- Can draw usage data from each separately
- It will be slower unless you were to need all three always

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Here is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `uid` = '$uniqueid' AND `cid` = '$contentid' AND `ct` = '$contenttype' AND `action` = '$action' ;
```

If you want a query like this to run fast, you want to use a composite index:

```
create index table_uid_cid_ct_action on table(uid, cid, ct, action)
```

This index will speed up any query on these four columns, where the conditions are all `=`.

Answer (score 0):

> Due of many action on this small system I want to know what is the
>   best practice on this, using multiple INT columns or 1 single VARCHAR
>   column, of course in performance terms.

Honestly, this is kind of like in college where a psychology major reads symptoms & starts to diagnose all their friends… Even themselves! MySQL optimization is something to keep in mind. But not just yet. Just program the way you feel it should work. And if performance becomes & issue only THEN optimize.

That said, I think your first example using `INT` columns makes much more sense from a MySQL structure point of view. The key is to create proper MySQL indexes which you can do after the fact once your codebase is a bit solid to speed things up.  And then past that you can decide if the storage engine—like MyISAM or InnoDB—is the best fit.

But that is all after the fact considerations.  And past any of that, I recommend using the [MySQL Tuning Primer Script located here](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) to fine tune your MySQL server once this goes into production.

And yes, I said production. You can attempt to tune a MySQL server on a development server, but it ultimately will never take on the traffic of a live server. So be ready to babysit the MySQL & code the first week (month?) of it going live.

Also, depending on your final setup you might need to learn how to performance tune by hand—meaning you learn to interpret MySQL output yourself and act on it—but this script works quite well for 95% of the setups I have ever used them on. The other 5% are database idiosyncratic setups that required more custom care. I highly recommend tutorials like [this one on the MySQL performance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/).